# Blender 2.8 closest_point_on_mesh returns incorrect face index

Tags: python, scripting

I have a mesh imported from MakeHuman with armature, subdivision and two mask modifiers. I need to find nearest vertex to some location.

If I use brute force cycle to iterate vertices and find vertex with min distance, it works fine, but is very slow and unusable.

Then I tried to use [`Object.closest_point_on_mesh`](https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.closest_point_on_mesh), but the problem is, although it returns correct hit location, it seems to be that face index is incorrect -- that face is far away from hit point.

```
vec = (0.1614, 0.0243, 0.1870)

(hit, loc, norm, face_index) = dest_object.closest_point_on_mesh(vec)

if hit:
    print('vector', vec)
    print('hit location', loc)
    print('face index', face_index)
    print('face vertex 0', dest_object.data.vertices[dest_object.data.polygons[face_index].vertices[0]].co)
    print('face center', dest_object.data.polygons[face_index].center)

nearest_poly = None
nearest_d = 0

for p in dest_object.data.polygons:
    if nearest_poly == None or nearest_d > dist_squared_v(vec, p.center):
        nearest_poly = p
        nearest_d = dist_squared_v(vec, p.center)

print('brute force face index', nearest_poly.index)
print('brute force face center', nearest_poly.center)
```

The output is:

```
vector (0.1614, 0.0243, 0.187)
hit location <Vector (0.1614, 0.0243, 0.1870)>
face index 12141
face vertex 0 <Vector (0.1684, -0.1665, 0.0024)>
face center <Vector (0.1670, -0.1649, 0.0013)>
brute force face index 12165
brute force face center <Vector (0.1609, 0.0237, 0.1852)>
```

As you can see from the output, hit location is correctly equal to my vector, but face center and face vertices are off. Brute force solution works fine, as expected.

I tried to delete SubSurf modifier, but nothing changed.

Is this a Blender bug or am I doing something wrong? Also, is there alternatives to closest_point_on_mesh?

---

Edit: here is visualisation of original location (vec, non-selected cube) and location of the center of the face found by closest_point_on_mesh (selected cube).

Cubes were created using this code:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.01, location=dest_object.matrix_world @ loc)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=0.01, location=dest_object.matrix_world @ dest_object.data.polygons[face_index].center)
```

[image]

Comment: The center is not necessarily the point of the face that is the closest. I guess closest_point_on_mesh is doing an orthogonal projection on the face (this projection is not at the center). To tell it another way, your brute force loop search for the face for which the center is the closest (and that's different).

Comment: @lemon I've attached a visualisation. These two boxes are spawned on precise positions of initial vector and the center of the found face. I can't imagine any projection or algorithm that gives me this face as a result, even if it considers vertex locations of the face instead of face center...

Comment: The image is small... hard to see the context. But have you looked at kdtree or bvhtree here? https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html (kdtree is probably hidden into closest point on mesh).

Comment: @lemon Thank you very much, I've used KDTree and it is as fast as closest_point_on_mesh. That solves my problem with finding nearest point, but I will not close or remove question because I want to know what's wrong with closest_point_on_mesh or my code that uses it.

Comment: For that, I've told you: closest point on mesh does not care about face center (you replied me but the image can't let me know where is what).

Comment: @lemon Here is upscaled and annotated image: https://imgur.com/a/4enJLiZ

Comment: `Object.closest_point_on_mesh(...)`  uses the evaluated mesh, whereas your "brute force" method doesn't.  Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: @batFINGER Can't find in Blender docs what evaluated mesh is, where I can read about it?

Comment: `closest_point_on_mesh(...)` uses a BVH tree.

Comment: Evaluated == with modifiers and shapes applied.